# How to find all package we can LoadNETType

Tags: packages, .netlink

After we `` Needs["NETLink`"] `` and `InstallNET[];`,we can use load many `.net` packages by `LoadNETType`,such as we can

```
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"]
```

Then we can use some extra functions from `` Clipboard` ``,and we can check it with `Names`

```
Names["Clipboard`*"]
```

> `` {Clipboard`Clear,Clipboard`ContainsAudio,Clipboard`ContainsData,Clipboard`ContainsFileDropList,Clipboard`ContainsImage,Clipboard`ContainsText,Clipboard`Equals,Clipboard`GetAudioStream,Clipboard`GetData,Clipboard`GetDataObject,Clipboard`GetFileDropList,Clipboard`GetImage,Clipboard`GetText,Clipboard`ReferenceEquals,Clipboard`SetAudio,Clipboard`SetData,Clipboard`SetDataObject,Clipboard`SetFileDropList,Clipboard`SetImage,Clipboard`SetText} ``

But how to find all `.net` packages in my local disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can get a list of all .NET types that can be loaded using `LoadNETType` like this:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

LoadedNETAssemblies[] //
Map[GetAssemblyObject[#]@GetTypes[]&] //
Flatten //
Map[#@FullName&] //
Sort //
Short[#, 5]&

(*
   { Accessibility.AnnoScope,Accessibility.CAccPropServices,
     Accessibility.CAccPropServicesClass,Accessibility.IAccessible,
     Accessibility.IAccessibleHandler,Accessibility.IAccIdentity,
     Accessibility.IAccPropServer,
     <<11369>>,
     Wolfram.NETLink.UI.ConsoleWindow+TextBoxStream,
     Wolfram.NETLink.UI.DoubleBufferedPanel,
     Wolfram.NETLink.UI.MathPictureBox,Wolfram.NETLink.UI.NamespaceDoc,
     Wolfram.NETLink.Utils,Wolfram.NETLink.WrappedKernelLink,
     Wolfram.NETLink.YieldFunction
   }
*)
```

To find all DLLs that can be loaded by `LoadNETAssembly`, we must perform a file system scan.  For example, to find all .NET assemblies under the Windows .NET *framework* directory:

```
LoadNETType["System.Reflection.AssemblyName", AllowShortContext->False];

FileNames["*.dll", "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework", Infinity] //
Select[Quiet[Check[System`Reflection`AssemblyName`GetAssemblyName[#]; True, False]]&] //
Sort //
Column

(*
  { "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v2.0.50727\\Accessibility.dll",
    "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v2.0.50727\\cscompmgd.dll",
    <<577>>,
    "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v4.0.30319\\WPF\\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll",
    "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v4.0.30319\\XamlBuildTask.dll",
    "c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v4.0.30319\\XsdBuildTask.dll"
  }
*)
```

Once we have loaded an assembly or type, we can use `NETTypeInfo` to get more information:

```
"c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v4.0.30319\\Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll" //
LoadNETAssembly //
NETTypeInfo
```

[image: NETTypeInfo screenshot]

```
"Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.FileLogger" //
LoadNETType //
NETTypeInfo
```

[image: NETTypeInfo screenshot]

Comment: Why your code cannot work when I write `LoadNETAssembly[
 FileNameJoin[{$TopDirectory, 
   "\\SystemFiles\\Links\\OpenCVLink\\LibraryResources\\Windows-x86-\
64\\opencv_stitching310.dll"}]]`

Comment: @yode That DLL does not contain a managed .NET assembly.  Note that the DLL does not pass the `GetAssemblyName` test.

Comment: Is there any method to glance that dll file by our *Mathematica*?

Comment: @yode I am not aware of any easy method that uses only _Mathematica_.  We could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the symbol table.  Or we could just read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d46/group__stitching.html) :)